# unable to install any npm pakage I try every thing but it didn't resolve i hope you guys resolve it thanks in advance

Tags: npm, proxy, config, connectivity, network-connection

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:90c3:80e2:e464:3f2:6810:22:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

I run all of the command in my terminal like  npm config delete http-proxy, npm config delete https-proxy and i also delete my .npmrc but it didn't work please help me to out of this thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a VPN(work) & behind a firewall? If that is the case then you'll need to set your work proxy in to the .npmrc file as mentioned below, otherwise in case of home network & no VPN empty .npmrc file should be fine. Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

```
proxy=http://WorkProxy.domain.com:80
https-proxy=http://WorkProxy.domain.com:80
strict-ssl=false
```

Note: In case of a firewall you might need to as well work with your IT security to make it work.